# Cannot log out of Google+

Tags: android, google-plus

## Android:

I am using GoogleApiClient class  to get access to Plus api for Signing into User's Google account. I have read the documentation from developers' site and I am using this code to log ou the user

```
private void signOutFromGplus()    //Sign out from Google
{
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
    {
        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
        Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
                .setResultCallback( new ResultCallback<Status>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status)
                    {
                        id.setText("User Disconnected");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Yeah, revoking the access too but still its not working.
How should I disconnect the User?

Comment: What does "not working" look like?

Comment: Try with just `mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccount();
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
{
    mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccount(); 
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
```

No need of `revokeAccessAndDisconnect()`. You are missing `disconnect`'s call, due to which its still connecting with old data, I guess.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void signOutFromGplus() {

    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        return;
    }

    // Clear the default account as in the Sign Out.
    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);

    // Revoke access to this entire application. This will call back
    // to onAccessRevoked when it is complete, as it needs to reach
    // the Google authentication servers to revoke all tokens.
    ResultCallback<Status> onAccessRevoked = new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            updateConnectButtonState();
            onPlusClientRevokeAccess();
        }
    };

    Plus.AccountApi
            .revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient)
            .setResultCallback(onAccessRevoked);

}
```

- Extracted from [Ian Barber's text](http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2014/02/migrating-from-plusclient-to.html).